# Partials for multiple modules on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have two modules. one is application and another is admin. On both the modules I have a footer.phtml in the following structure.

Application > view > application > partial
Admin > view > admin > partial

I have also setup the path to the partial folder as follwing in module.config.php

For application module

```
    'template_path_stack' => array(
    'app' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    'appPartial' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/partial',
    ),
```

and for admin module

```
    'template_path_stack' => array(
    'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    'partial' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/partial',
    ),
```

But whenever I use partial('footer.phtml')?> in any layout, it always load the footer from admin module.
I know I can use partial('application/partial/footer.phtml')?>, but I want to know if there is a way by using template_path_stack only.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define partials in your template stack in both modules. Keeping in mind the keys must be different. And then use the key instead of filename. Like in your case you have `appPartial` and `partial`.

You can load partial using these keys.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial'); ?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo $this->partial('appPartial'); ?>
```

**Upadte:**

You can categories your layouts in sub directories.

```
layout/
   admin/
      layout.phtml
   login/
   partials/
   layout.phtml
```

If you have common partial, you can include it on all layouts without defining it again. You can use defined key in your `layout.phtml`

**Update:**

Here is my code to implement different layouts on different controllers in same module. May be you find something useful.

```
if ($controllerName == "Application\Controller\Index") {
     if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/view/layout/layout.phtml')) {
            $controller->layout('layout/layout');
     }
} else if ($controllerName == "Application\Controller\Admin" && $statusCode != "404") {
     if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/view/layout/admin/layout.phtml')) {
            $controller->layout('admin/layout');
     }
} else {
     if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/view/layout/layout.phtml')) {
            $controller->layout('layout/layout');
     }
}
```

`admin/layout` and `layout/layout` are defined as

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/_top'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/_top.phtml',
            'layout/_header_navigation'           => __DIR__ . /../view/layout/_header_navigation.phtml',
            'layout/_footer_navigation'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/_footer_navigation.phtml',
            'layout/_footer'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/_footer.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            'admin/layout'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin/layout.phtml',
            'admin/layout/login'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin/login.phtml',
            'admin/layout/leftpanel' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin/_leftpanel.phtml',
            'admin/layout/headerpanel' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin/_headerpanel.phtml',
            'jstranslations' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/_jstranslations.phtml',
            'partial/_regional_searh_lists' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/_regional_search_lists.phtml',
            'partial/_paginator' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/_paginator.phtml',
            'email/deleted_user' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/_deleted_user_message_template.phtml',
            'email/deleting_user' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/_deleting_user_message_template.phtml',
            'email/delete_account' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/_delete_account.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

In `module.config.php`

Comment: yes, this could be a option. but I have 4 different modules, and each has 4 different layout. And it seems obvious to name the footer portion of all the layouts as footer.phtml, no?

Comment: As footer and header files are usually common. Best if you need to use different layouts like admin, login, frontend screens, then the best approach is to define separate layouts in your layotus folder in any module. Obviously these new layouts will have different footer, header partials. And just apply that layout in your module class `Module.php`. You can separate layouts at directory level as you will be using keys from template path stack. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Bilal, first thank you for the quick answers. :)

The partials are not common except that they have the same filename.
I agree with you that I can use different folder structure to differentiate the partial keys. But this would be the same as using fully qualified partial path as 

$this->partial('application/partial/footer.phtml')
$this->partial('admin/partial/footer.phtml')

This would be cumbersome, :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use path_stack, you'll need two differents view aliases. Otherwise, the last to come in configuration will overwrite the others, as this is your case.

You can also use a template map, at least for specifics views like your footer. The other bonus is that template map is more performant.

Comment: hi jmleroux,
yes, we can map the different partials using template_map on module.config.php.
for eg. 
 'template_map' => array(
            'apppartial'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/partial/footer.phtml',
        ),

and we can use <?=$this->partial('apppartial')?> to render the partial. The trick would be to use different keys for the partial as you said. But then we will soon fill the template_map with partial paths. This does not sound good.

Comment: It's not a trick, but a good practice to name your views with clear names. A name like 'mymodule/footer' is better than 'footer', because you can quickly identify the first. I don't really understand why filling the template map with partials sounds bad (it is way more performant than path_stack), but you can just use template_map for the specifics views, like your footers, and keep path_stack for the others.

Comment: we cannot also use the template_map all the times. It does not sound smart if we need to populate the template_map every time we create a new partial. The issue is not only with a single footer.phtml. What would you do if we have, lets say, 25 partials on each module. I agree with you that template_map would be more performer, but believe me this is not always the best idea.